# jquery .css function not working after ajax success

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

i have this css which makes div unclickable

```
.commentpost{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

with this html

```
<div class="commentsDiv">
//some code to show the comments from db
//
  <div class="w-100">
      <div class="div-bottom-3 d-flex " style="position: absolute;">
           <div class="form__group">
                <input type="text" class="form__input comment" id="comment" 
                    placeholder="Add a comment" name="comment"/>
           </div>
           <div class="pt-1 commentpost">
                Post
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // makes commentpost div clickable if input is not empty
  $('.comment').keyup(function() {
    $('.commentpost').css('pointer-events','auto');
    if(!$.trim($('.comment').val()).length){
      $('.commentpost').css('pointer-events','none');
    }

 $('.commentpost').on('click',function(e){
     //ajax call happens
     //and on success reload div commentsDiv with .load()
 })
});
```

after ajax success it saves the comment in db and shows it in another div but I cant press the post div again, pointer-event stays none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea,

try doing this,

```
 $(document).on('click','.commentpost',function(e){
     //ajax call happens
     //and on success reload div commentsDiv with .load()
 })
```

using the document to understand if there is a clickable element, since I think you have the clickable div being changed.

It works good because if elements are being dynamically created via ajax jquery, you go to understand that those new divs did not exist on document ready, only the original one, so document on click looks at what exists in the document currently everytime and prevents event bubbling when divs changes

Comment: thanks dude this + placing the clickable div outside the loaded div made it work

Comment: No problem, when I write .on click, I always write it in that fashion I described above, I cant think of a reason not to, especially if you ever have multiple things happening on a div at different times or if elements are created by jquery, same thing with .on keyup same setup above is always best to use.